# How do I sum the number of times multiple strings are in a column in Python using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

** Closed **

```
noLizard = animals[animals["Pets"] != "Lizard"
print(len(noLizard))
```

How do I print the sum of the number of times dog and cat appears in the column pet using pandas?
I tried to use count_value() but it outputs the number each unique pet occurs. I want the output to be 5.

| Age | Pet |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | Dog |
| 5 | Dog |
| 4 | Cat |
| 3 | Dog |
| 1 | Lizard |
| 4 | Cat |
| 2 | Lizard |

Comment: Take a look at [the count function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html)

Answer (score 0):

To show how many rows have either dog or cat you can do:

```
animals[animals['Pet'].isin(['Dog', 'Cat'])].shape[0]
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I do it without writing out dog and cat? I want to report everything besides lizards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas.Series.isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) or [pandas.Series.str.contains()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to check if Series value in list or matches some pattern.

```py
sum(animals['Pet'].isin(['Dog', 'Cat']))
```

Or

```py
sum(animals['Pet'].str.contains('Dog|Cat'))
```

If you want to use [pandas.Series.value_counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

```py
counts = animals['Pet'].value_counts()

res = sum([counts[k] for k in ['Dog', 'Cat']])
```

Answer (score 0):

For only, `dog and cat` use `isin` :

```
print(df.Pet.isin(['Dog','Cat']).sum()) # 5

# via value_counts()
prting(df.Pet.value_counts()[['Dog','Cat']].sum())
```

If you want to count the occurrence of all diff pets in the `pet` column use:

```
print(df.Pet.value_counts()) 

# or via Counter 

from collections import Counter
print(Counter(df.Pet.values)) # Counter({'Dog': 3, 'Cat': 2, 'Lizard': 2})
```

If you want everything apart from 'Lizard' use:

```
print(len(df[df.Pet != 'Lizard']))
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I do it without writing out dog and cat? I want to report everything besides lizards.